# Retag/synonym request: "webbrowser" -> "browser"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

It seems like the [webbrowser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webbrowser) (5 questions) tag needs to be merged into and become synonymous with [browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser) (702 questions) (per the definition of the latter tag). I'd do it manually, but I can't suggest a synonym. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done!

```
updating post history, 5 rows affected
updating posts, 5 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [browser] and [webbrowser] complete!
Deleting Synonym browser -> webbrowser
Tag Synonym webbrowser -> browser was approved!
```

Thanks for the heads-up.